# Matching Square Webhook signature in Ruby (on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webhooks, hmac, square-connect

I am trying to match the X-Square-Signature header as documented here: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#validating-notifications

I am currently using OpenSSL::HMAC to generate the digest but things seem to be incorrect.

```
string_to_sign = "#{request.url}#{param_hash.to_json}"
header_signature = request.headers["X-Square-Signature"]

# split into multiple lines for clarity
digest = OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha1')
hmac = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(digest, ENV["SIGNATURE_KEY"], string_to_sign)

# stripping the newline off the end
hmac_64 = Base64.encode64(hmac).strip
```

For some reason I am getting a drastically different digest, despite following the instructions provided in the API docs above. My calculation of the digest seems to line up with their python example as well (https://github.com/square/connect-api-examples/blob/master/connect-examples/v1/webhooks.py#L75-L87).

I have verified the string_to_sign value is identical to the pattern I am supposed to follow, and when I manually craft a post it works, but I am generating my signature through this same method so of course it lines up.

Are there any particulars to the digest/signature calculation process I could be overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the source of your problem, but you should use `request.raw_post` instead of `param_hash.to_json`. The request body is a json object and there is no canonical ordering of attributes on a json object. When you convert the param hash back to json, there's no guarantee that the attributes are in the same order as in the original request body.

Try again using

```
string_to_sign = "#{request.url}#{request.raw_post}"
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to replicate the example in the Square docs.  You mentioned you verified that `string_to_sign` is `http://www.example.com{"merchant_id":"JGHJ0343","event_type":"PAYMENT_UPDATED","entity_id":"Jq74mCczmFXk1tC10GB"}`, but have you verified that the environment variable `SIGNATURE_KEY` is `EXAMPLE_SECRET_123` as in the docs?

Your code as written with the values substituted and setting the environment variable computes the hash as given in the example: `DBP9woNqJpO4d4/ZFE7xveLIGPU=`

Comment: my SIGNATURE_KEY is the one provided to me by the Webhook control panel on square's website, I have verified they are matching. the EXAMPLE_SECRET_123 is just a placeholder for showing the functionality.